# How to use hex color values

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I am trying to use hex color values in Swift, instead of the few standard ones that `UIColor` allows you to use, but I have no idea how to do it.

Example: how would I use `#ffffff` as a color?

Comment: `#ffffff` are actually 3 color components in hexadecimal notation - red `ff`, green `ff` and blue `ff`. You can write hexadecimal notation in Swift using `0x` prefix, e.g `0xFF`.

Comment: The answer here should help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196528/swift-uicolor-initializer-compiler-error-only-when-targeting-iphone5s.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use UIColorFromRGB value in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074257/how-to-use-uicolorfromrgb-value-in-swift)

Answer (score 784, accepted):

`#ffffff` are actually 3 color components in hexadecimal notation - red `ff`, green `ff` and blue `ff`. You can write hexadecimal notation in Swift using `0x` prefix, e.g `0xFF`

To simplify the conversion, let's create an initializer that takes integer (0 - 255) values:

```
extension UIColor {
   convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
       assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
       assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
       assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")

       self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
   }

   convenience init(rgb: Int) {
       self.init(
           red: (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF,
           green: (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF,
           blue: rgb & 0xFF
       )
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
let color = UIColor(red: 0xFF, green: 0xFF, blue: 0xFF)
let color2 = UIColor(rgb: 0xFFFFFF)
```

**How to get alpha?**

Depending on your use case, you can simply use the native `UIColor.withAlphaComponent` method, e.g.

```
let semitransparentBlack = UIColor(rgb: 0x000000).withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Or you can add an additional (optional) parameter to the above methods:

```
convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int, a: CGFloat = 1.0) {
    self.init(
        red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0,
        alpha: a
    )
}

convenience init(rgb: Int, a: CGFloat = 1.0) {
    self.init(
        red: (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF,
        green: (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF,
        blue: rgb & 0xFF,
        a: a
    )
}
```

(we cannot name the parameter `alpha` because of a name collision with the existing initializer).

Called as:

```
let color = UIColor(red: 0xFF, green: 0xFF, blue: 0xFF, a: 0.5)
let color2 = UIColor(rgb: 0xFFFFFF, a: 0.5)
```

To get the alpha as an integer 0-255, we can

```
convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int, a: Int = 0xFF) {
    self.init(
        red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(a) / 255.0
    )
}

// let's suppose alpha is the first component (ARGB)
convenience init(argb: Int) {
    self.init(
        red: (argb >> 16) & 0xFF,
        green: (argb >> 8) & 0xFF,
        blue: argb & 0xFF,
        a: (argb >> 24) & 0xFF
    )
}
```

Called as

```
let color = UIColor(red: 0xFF, green: 0xFF, blue: 0xFF, a: 0xFF)
let color2 = UIColor(argb: 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

Or a combination of the previous methods. There is absolutely no need to use strings.

Comment: @Sulthan Could you please also define an extension with alpha and hex value?

Comment: @confile No, because that's not standardized. Alpha can be the first component or the last. If you need alpha, just add one parameter `alpha`

Comment: @Sulthan Can I set alpha after the color has been created?

Comment: @confile Colors are immutable, so no, you have to create a new color with changed alpha.

Comment: Same solution, Swift 1.2 compatible, with alpha support: https://gist.github.com/berikv/ecf1f79c5bc9921c47ef

Comment: 3 drops of albine unicorn tears, a dash of meteorite dust tossed into the magma of a millenial eruption... Still easier than setting a color hahah, anyways it works!

Comment: assert(red >= 0 ... ) - why not use UInt and let the compiler take care of that for you?

Comment: For explanation of how this works, see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) Apple Doc

Comment: Why not use UInt8 instead of asserting that your ints are in range 0...255?

Comment: @jrc @RichardVenable Apple recommends to use `Int` even when only unsigned values are expected. Using one type simplifies operations, especially when we are working in a language without implicit casts.

Comment: Nice, but too lengthy, Here I have written a short method for this purpose
https://handyopinion.com/method-to-convert-hexadecimal-color-code-into-uicolor-swift/

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry Lengthy? Technically it's a one-liner. You are parsing a string which is rarely needed and the same is written here in 5 answers already.

Comment: Great solution, I added *UIColor.init(rgb: Constants.Color.mainColor).cgColor* personally

Answer (score 430):

**This is a function that takes a hex string and returns a UIColor.**
*(You can enter hex strings with either format: `#ffffff` or `ffffff`)*

**Usage:**

```
var color1 = hexStringToUIColor("#d3d3d3")
```

**Swift 5:** (Swift 4+)

```
func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt64 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

**Swift 2:**

```
func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet() as NSCharacterSet).uppercaseString

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
      cString = cString.substringFromIndex(cString.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
    }

    if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
      return UIColor.grayColor()
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    NSScanner(string: cString).scanHexInt(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

---

Source: [arshad/gist:de147c42d7b3063ef7bc](https://gist.github.com/arshad/de147c42d7b3063ef7bc)

*Edit: Updated the code.  Thanks, Hlung, jaytrixz, Ahmad F, Kegham K, and Adam Waite!*

Comment: `countelements` is now just `count` :)

Comment: @Hlung and @ethanstrider it looks like they don't even let you do `count` now instead of `countElements`, any idea what they want us to use?

Comment: Before Swift 2.0, count was a global function. As of Swift 2.0, it can be called as a member function (i.e. aString.count).

Comment: Changed this line of code `cString = cString.substringFromIndex(advance(cString.startIndex, 1))` to `cString = cString.substringFromIndex(cString.startIndex.advancedBy(1))` for Swift 2.2 Xcode 7.3

Comment: And all you have to do for *Swift 4* is to remove `characters` from `cString.characters.count` :)

Comment: If you are still supporting iPhone 5 or any 32 bit devices prior to iOS 11 it will crash. You need to change the `UInt32` to `UInt64`

Comment: Xcode 11 and the iOS13 SDK deprecates `scanHexInt32`. Use a `UInt64` and `scanHexInt64` instead.

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 250):

**Swift 5 (Swift 4, Swift 3)** UIColor extension:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hexString: String) {
        let hex = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
        var int = UInt64()
        Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt64(&int)
        let a, r, g, b: UInt64
        switch hex.count {
        case 3: // RGB (12-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, (int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)
        case 6: // RGB (24-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        case 8: // ARGB (32-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (int >> 24, int >> 16 & 0xFF, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        default:
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, 0, 0, 0)
        }
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r) / 255, green: CGFloat(g) / 255, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255, alpha: CGFloat(a) / 255)
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
let darkGrey = UIColor(hexString: "#757575")
```

**Swift 2.x** version:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hexString: String) {
        let hex = hexString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().invertedSet)
        var int = UInt32()
        NSScanner(string: hex).scanHexInt(&int)
        let a, r, g, b: UInt32
        switch hex.characters.count {
        case 3: // RGB (12-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, (int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)
        case 6: // RGB (24-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        case 8: // ARGB (32-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (int >> 24, int >> 16 & 0xFF, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        default:
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, 0, 0, 0)
        }
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r) / 255, green: CGFloat(g) / 255, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255, alpha: CGFloat(a) / 255)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my favorite implementation because of the way it handles the 3 cases. But I prefer the default: case to return nil, instead of white.

Comment: by the way, the default case in this implementation seems to be UIColor.yellow()

Comment: I know how to use it and it works like a charm. But I don't really understand why. Maybe someone can give me an explanation or some good links/words to search?

Comment: This does not work correctly with alpha values.  e.g. Both inputs "ff00ff00" and "#ff00ff00" will output an RGBA of 0 1 0 1.  (It should be 1 0 1 0). The input "#ff00ff" results in 1 0 1 1, which is correct.  (Xcode 8.2.1, iOS 9.3.)

Comment: @Womble the first component is the alpha not the last one. So "#ff00ff00" has alpha 1 because of the "ff" at the beginning. I think you meant "#00ff00ff". Another example: "#ff00ff00" this is green with alpha 1, "#0000ff00" this is green with alpha 0

Comment: 'scanHexInt32' was deprecated in iOS 13.0

Comment: @PeterLapisu true, I updated the snippet, now we use UInt64

Comment: Hey can someone please explain why in the case of 12-bit we need to multiple 17?

Comment: nvm, I got this, because 12-bits HEX is Shorthand hexadecimal form.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uicolor/how-to-convert-a-hex-color-to-a-uicolor

Answer (score 93):

`UIColor`:

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(hex: Int) {
        let components = (
            R: CGFloat((hex >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
            G: CGFloat((hex >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
            B: CGFloat((hex >> 00) & 0xff) / 255
        )
        self.init(red: components.R, green: components.G, blue: components.B, alpha: 1)
    }

}
```

`CGColor`:

```
extension CGColor {

    class func colorWithHex(hex: Int) -> CGColorRef {

        return UIColor(hex: hex).CGColor

    }

}
```

---

**Usage**

```
let purple = UIColor(hex: 0xAB47BC)
```

Comment: In my humble opinion, I found this the easiest to use and very clear compared to other answers.

Comment: How would you handle 123ABC? The compiler is burking at it not being a digit.

Comment: for completeness: `let foo: Int = 0x123ABC` - note the '0x'

Comment: Alas, like many other hex converters, this doesn't handle alpha components. So, for example, you can't get a UIColor.clear value from it.

Comment: While it doesn't handle alpha @Womble, it's trivial to add. I had to set an explicit type for "components" to prevent the Swift compiler from "taking too long" and giving up.

Comment: Is anyone else getting a crash here?

Comment: Cleanest answer. I prefer this to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 49):

I've merged a few ideas from this thread of answers and updated it for **iOS 13 & Swift 5**.

```
extension UIColor {
  
  convenience init(_ hex: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
    var cString = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
    
    if cString.hasPrefix("#") { cString.removeFirst() }
    
    if cString.count != 6 {
      self.init("ff0000") // return red color for wrong hex input
      return
    }
    
    var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
    
    self.init(red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
              green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
              blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
              alpha: alpha)
  }

}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
UIColor("#ff0000") // with #
UIColor("ff0000")  // without #
UIColor("ff0000", alpha: 0.5) // using optional alpha value
```

Answer (score 46):

**Swift 4** : Combining the answers of Sulthan and Luca Torella :

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hexFromString:String, alpha:CGFloat = 1.0) {
        var cString:String = hexFromString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 10066329 //color #999999 if string has wrong format

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
        }

        if ((cString.count) == 6) {
            Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)
        }

        self.init(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: alpha
        )
    }
}
```

Usage examples:

```
let myColor = UIColor(hexFromString: "4F9BF5")

let myColor = UIColor(hexFromString: "#4F9BF5")

let myColor = UIColor(hexFromString: "#4F9BF5", alpha: 0.5)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, thank u very much.

Answer (score 35):

### Swift 5.3 & SwiftUI: Hex and CSS color name support via a UIColor

[Gist code](https://gist.github.com/nbasham/3b2de0566d5f716894fc)

[Swift Package](https://github.com/NormanBitSolace/BlackLabsColor)

[SwiftUI Package](https://github.com/nbasham/BlackLabsSwiftUIColor)

**Example strings:**

- `Orange`, `Lime`, `Tomato`, etc.
- `Clear`, `Transparent`, `nil`, and empty string yield `[UIColor clearColor]`
- `abc`
- `abc7`
- `#abc7`
- `00FFFF`
- `#00FFFF`
- `00FFFF77`

**Playground output:**
[image: Playground output]

Answer (score 27):

The simplest way to add color programmatically is by using **ColorLiteral**.

Just add the property ColorLiteral as shown in the example, Xcode will prompt you with a whole list of colors which you can choose. The advantage of doing so is lesser code, **add HEX values or RGB**. You will also get the recently used colors from the storyboard.

**Example:** 
self.view.backgroundColor = ColorLiteral
[image]

Comment: Wow! you are the champ... I was looking for a really simple solution... This is the one... Cheers...

Comment: This is useful!

Comment: Currently the easiest and the best solution if the color is not set dynamically

Comment: Does ColorLitreal support Hex Color Code?

Comment: @Saurav_97 choose other option which you can see it in the attached image above and you will be able to set Hex value

Answer (score 24):

With Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7.0.1 you can create this function:

```
    // Creates a UIColor from a Hex string.
    func colorWithHexString (hex:String) -> UIColor {
        var cString:String = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).uppercaseString

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString = (cString as NSString).substringFromIndex(1)
        }

        if (cString.characters.count != 6) {
            return UIColor.grayColor()
        }

        let rString = (cString as NSString).substringToIndex(2)
        let gString = ((cString as NSString).substringFromIndex(2) as NSString).substringToIndex(2)
        let bString = ((cString as NSString).substringFromIndex(4) as NSString).substringToIndex(2)

        var r:CUnsignedInt = 0, g:CUnsignedInt = 0, b:CUnsignedInt = 0;
        NSScanner(string: rString).scanHexInt(&r)
        NSScanner(string: gString).scanHexInt(&g)
        NSScanner(string: bString).scanHexInt(&b)


        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(1))
    }
```

and then use it in this way:

```
let color1 = colorWithHexString("#1F437C")
```

**Updated For Swift 4**

```
func colorWithHexString (hex:String) -> UIColor {

    var cString = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString = (cString as NSString).substring(from: 1)
    }

    if (cString.characters.count != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    let rString = (cString as NSString).substring(to: 2)
    let gString = ((cString as NSString).substring(from: 2) as NSString).substring(to: 2)
    let bString = ((cString as NSString).substring(from: 4) as NSString).substring(to: 2)

    var r:CUnsignedInt = 0, g:CUnsignedInt = 0, b:CUnsignedInt = 0;
    Scanner(string: rString).scanHexInt32(&r)
    Scanner(string: gString).scanHexInt32(&g)
    Scanner(string: bString).scanHexInt32(&b)


    return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(1))
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Here's what I'm using. Works with 6 and 8 character color strings, with or without the # symbol. Defaults to black in release and crashes in debug when initialized with an invalid string.

```
extension UIColor {
    public convenience init(hex: String) {
        var r: CGFloat = 0
        var g: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        var a: CGFloat = 1

        let hexColor = hex.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
        var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0
        var valid = false

        if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {
            if hexColor.count == 8 {
                r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
                b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255
                valid = true
            }
            else if hexColor.count == 6 {
                r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255
                g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff00) >> 8) / 255
                b = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x0000ff) / 255
                valid = true
            }
        }

        #if DEBUG
            assert(valid, "UIColor initialized with invalid hex string")
        #endif

        self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
UIColor(hex: "#75CC83FF")
UIColor(hex: "75CC83FF")
UIColor(hex: "#75CC83")
UIColor(hex: "75CC83")
```

Comment: I searched a lot.And finally found.Thanks @Erik

Answer (score 17):

**Warning "'scanHexInt32' was deprecated in iOS 13.0" was fixed.**

The sample should work on Swift2.2 and above(Swift2.x, Swift3.x, Swift4.x, Swift5.x):

```
extension UIColor {

    // hex sample: 0xf43737
    convenience init(_ hex: Int, alpha: Double = 1.0) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat((hex >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.0, green: CGFloat((hex >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat((hex) & 0xFF) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(255 * alpha) / 255)
    }

    convenience init(_ hexString: String, alpha: Double = 1.0) {
        let hex = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
        var int = UInt64()
        Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt64(&int)

        let r, g, b: UInt64
        switch hex.count {
        case 3: // RGB (12-bit)
            (r, g, b) = ((int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)
        case 6: // RGB (24-bit)
            (r, g, b) = (int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        default:
            (r, g, b) = (1, 1, 0)
        }

        self.init(red: CGFloat(r) / 255, green: CGFloat(g) / 255, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255, alpha: CGFloat(255 * alpha) / 255)
    }

    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat = 1) {
        self.init(red: (r / 255), green: (g / 255), blue: (b / 255), alpha: a)
    }
}
```

Use them like below:

```
UIColor(0xF54A45)
UIColor(0xF54A45, alpha: 0.7)
UIColor("#f44")
UIColor("#f44", alpha: 0.7)
UIColor("#F54A45")
UIColor("#F54A45", alpha: 0.7)
UIColor("F54A45")
UIColor("F54A45", alpha: 0.7)
UIColor(r: 245.0, g: 73, b: 69)
UIColor(r: 245.0, g: 73, b: 69, a: 0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: 'scanHexInt32' was deprecated in iOS 13.0

Comment: @Dimitar Stefanovski I've fixed that.

Answer (score 16):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string) answer shows how to do it in Obj-C. The bridge is to use

```
let rgbValue = 0xFFEEDD
let r = Float((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0
let g = Float((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0
let b = Float((rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 5:** You can create colors in Xcode as explained in the following two images:

[image]

You should name the color because you reference the color by the name. As shown in image 2:

[image]

Comment: I didn't realise you could define colours as Assets. Really glad I found this answer!

Comment: Hex option seems to have disappeared but this idea got me somewhere

Comment: i cant find the color pane on the right in xcode 13.  was it removed?

Answer (score 6):

Another method

**Swift 3.0**

Write a extension for UIColor

```
// To change the HexaDecimal value to Corresponding Color
extension UIColor
{
    class func uicolorFromHex(_ rgbValue:UInt32, alpha : CGFloat)->UIColor

    {
        let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0
        let blue = CGFloat(rgbValue & 0xFF) / 255.0
        return UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

you can directly create UIColor with hex like this

```
let carrot = UIColor.uicolorFromHex(0xe67e22, alpha: 1))
```

Answer (score 6):

**Xcode 13.2.1, M1, Swift 5.5**

We can use Hex in ColorLiterals

type `#colorLiteral(` in Xcode and that will trigger and fix the bug related to **ColorLiterals**

**then click in other**

[image]

**and then select RGB slider and you can see now the panel for Hex**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Swift extension on `UIColor` that takes a hex string:

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {

    convenience init(hexString: String) {
        // Trim leading '#' if needed
        var cleanedHexString = hexString
        if hexString.hasPrefix("#") {
//            cleanedHexString = dropFirst(hexString) // Swift 1.2
            cleanedHexString = String(hexString.characters.dropFirst()) // Swift 2
        }

        // String -> UInt32
        var rgbValue: UInt32 = 0
        NSScanner(string: cleanedHexString).scanHexInt(&rgbValue)

        // UInt32 -> R,G,B
        let red = CGFloat((rgbValue >> 16) & 0xff) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat((rgbValue >> 08) & 0xff) / 255.0
        let blue = CGFloat((rgbValue >> 00) & 0xff) / 255.0

        self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

}
```

Comment: what is drop drop first ?

Answer (score 5):

**Latest swift3 Version**

```
        extension UIColor {
convenience init(hexString: String) {
    let hex = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
    var int = UInt32()
    Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt32(&int)
    let a, r, g, b: UInt32
    switch hex.characters.count {
    case 3: // RGB (12-bit)
        (a, r, g, b) = (255, (int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)
    case 6: // RGB (24-bit)
        (a, r, g, b) = (255, int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
    case 8: // ARGB (32-bit)
        (a, r, g, b) = (int >> 24, int >> 16 & 0xFF, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
    default:
        (a, r, g, b) = (255, 0, 0, 0)
    }
      self.init(red: CGFloat(r) / 255, green: CGFloat(g) / 255, blue:      CGFloat(b) / 255, alpha: CGFloat(a) / 255)
}
}
```

Use in your class or where ever you converted into hexcolor to uicolor like in this way

```
             let color1 = UIColor(hexString: "#FF323232")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public static func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.characters.count) == 6) {

        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }else if ((cString.characters.count) == 8) {

        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x000000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0
        )
    }else{
        return UIColor.gray
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
var color: UIColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#00ff00"); // Without transparency
var colorWithTransparency: UIColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#dd00ff00"); // With transparency
```

Answer (score 5):

## Simple Color Extension for Swift 5/SwiftUI

**Example:**

```
let myColor = Color(hex:0xF2C94C)
```

**Code:**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hex: Int) {
        let components = (
            R: CGFloat((hex >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
            G: CGFloat((hex >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
            B: CGFloat((hex >> 00) & 0xff) / 255
        )
        self.init(red: components.R, green: components.G, blue: components.B, alpha: 1)
    }
}

extension Color {
    public init(hex: Int) {
        self.init(UIColor(hex: hex))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Hex with validation

> Based on [Eduardo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51236967/4488252) answer

### Details

- Xcode 10.0, Swift 4.2
- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Solution

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {

    convenience init(r: UInt8, g: UInt8, b: UInt8, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        let divider: CGFloat = 255.0
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r)/divider, green: CGFloat(g)/divider, blue: CGFloat(b)/divider, alpha: alpha)
    }

    private convenience init(rgbWithoutValidation value: Int32, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        self.init(
            r: UInt8((value & 0xFF0000) >> 16),
            g: UInt8((value & 0x00FF00) >> 8),
            b: UInt8(value & 0x0000FF),
            alpha: alpha
        )
    }

    convenience init?(rgb: Int32, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        if rgb > 0xFFFFFF || rgb < 0 { return nil }
        self.init(rgbWithoutValidation: rgb, alpha: alpha)
    }

    convenience init?(hex: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        var charSet = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines
        charSet.insert("#")
        let _hex = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: charSet)
        guard _hex.range(of: "^[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}$", options: .regularExpression) != nil else { return nil }
        var rgb: UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: _hex).scanHexInt32(&rgb)
        self.init(rgbWithoutValidation: Int32(rgb), alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let alpha: CGFloat = 1.0

// Hex
print(UIColor(rgb: 0x4F9BF5) ?? "nil")
print(UIColor(rgb: 0x4F9BF5, alpha: alpha) ?? "nil")
print(UIColor(rgb: 5217269) ?? "nil")
print(UIColor(rgb: -5217269) ?? "nil")                  // = nil
print(UIColor(rgb: 0xFFFFFF1) ?? "nil")                 // = nil

// String
print(UIColor(hex: "4F9BF5") ?? "nil")
print(UIColor(hex: "4F9BF5", alpha: alpha) ?? "nil")
print(UIColor(hex: "#4F9BF5") ?? "nil")
print(UIColor(hex: "#4F9BF5", alpha: alpha) ?? "nil")
print(UIColor(hex: "#4F9BF56") ?? "nil")                // = nil
print(UIColor(hex: "#blabla") ?? "nil")                 // = nil

// RGB
print(UIColor(r: 79, g: 155, b: 245))
print(UIColor(r: 79, g: 155, b: 245, alpha: alpha))
//print(UIColor(r: 792, g: 155, b: 245, alpha: alpha))  // Compiler will throw an error, r,g,b = [0...255]
```

Comment: You don't need `NSPredicate` just to test regular expressions. `string.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression)` works too.

Answer (score 3):

### Swift 5.0

You cannot use the `#ffffff` syntax directly in Swift. Here is the code I use for web-related projects. Supports alpha and three-digits.

**Usage example** (uppercase values are fine too):

```swift
    let hex = "#FADE2B"  // yellow
    let color = UIColor(fromHex: hex)
```

**Supported string formats**:

- `"fff"  // RGB`
- `"#fff"  // #RGB`
- `"ffff"  // RGBA`
- `"#ffff"  // #RGBA`
- `"ffffff"  // RRGGBB`
- `"#ffffff"  // #RRGGBB`
- `"ffffffff"  // RRGGBBAA`
- `"#ffffffff"  // #RRGGBBAA`

The digits represent **R**ed, **G**reen, **B**lue and **A**lpha (like transparency).

**Code**:

```swift
    extension UIColor {
        /// Initialises UIColor from a hexadecimal string. Color is clear if string is invalid.
        /// - Parameter fromHex: supported formats are "#RGB", "#RGBA", "#RRGGBB", "#RRGGBBAA", with or without the # character
        public convenience init(fromHex:String) {
            var r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 255
            let offset = fromHex.hasPrefix("#") ? 1 : 0
            let ch = fromHex.map{$0}
            switch(ch.count - offset) {
            case 8:
                a = 16 * (ch[offset+6].hexDigitValue ?? 0) + (ch[offset+7].hexDigitValue ?? 0)
                fallthrough
            case 6:
                r = 16 * (ch[offset+0].hexDigitValue ?? 0) + (ch[offset+1].hexDigitValue ?? 0)
                g = 16 * (ch[offset+2].hexDigitValue ?? 0) + (ch[offset+3].hexDigitValue ?? 0)
                b = 16 * (ch[offset+4].hexDigitValue ?? 0) + (ch[offset+5].hexDigitValue ?? 0)
                break
            case 4:
                a = 16 * (ch[offset+3].hexDigitValue ?? 0) + (ch[offset+3].hexDigitValue ?? 0)
                fallthrough
            case 3:  // Three digit #0D3 is the same as six digit #00DD33
                r = 16 * (ch[offset+0].hexDigitValue ?? 0) + (ch[offset+0].hexDigitValue ?? 0)
                g = 16 * (ch[offset+1].hexDigitValue ?? 0) + (ch[offset+1].hexDigitValue ?? 0)
                b = 16 * (ch[offset+2].hexDigitValue ?? 0) + (ch[offset+2].hexDigitValue ?? 0)
                break
            default:
                a = 0
                break
            }
            self.init(red: CGFloat(r)/255, green: CGFloat(g)/255, blue: CGFloat(b)/255, alpha: CGFloat(a)/255)
            
        }
    }
    // Author: Andrew Kingdom
```

**IMPORTANT** This is written for iOS (UIKit). For MacOS (AppKit), replace `UIColor` with `NSColor`.

*License: CC BY*

I find this less messy for copy/pasting than the following

**Alternatives**:

You can remove the `#` and store it as a 32-bit unsigned integer literal, denoted by a `0x` prefix thus: 0xffffff. You still need code to convert this to a colour though.

If you're wanting a non-programatic way to get the color: Open a colour selector dialog and switch to Colour Sliders > RGB Sliders and paste/enter the value into the 'Hex Color #' box. (Don't paste the # hash symbol.)

**Caveat**:

Hex colours originating from Android are usually in format AARRGGBB and will thus require reformatting. e.g. `let newColor = color.suffix(6).prefix(4) + color.prefix(2)`

**Source**:

https://gist.github.com/akingdom/75778998e0d435060d645c0be35f9c24

Comment: Edit: Fixed bugs and clarified the explanation.

Comment: It's Swift 5 but you still use `NS´Color?

Comment: @Siamaster I've switched the code to focus on iOS. You missed the instruction 'For iOS, replace NSColor with UIColor' since MacOS/AppKit still uses NSColor in Swift5.

Comment: Ahaa! I had no idea :) Thanks for the clarification :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use it in swift 5

**SWIFT 5**

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    static func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
        var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
        }

        if ((cString.count) != 6) {
            return UIColor.gray
        }

        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the original question it isn't clear whether the hex value is a String or an Int. Given that in the original question the hex value starts with `#` rather than `0x`, let's assume it is a String. All the answers posted here so far are using the ancient `NSScanner`/ `Scanner` object to parse the string. There's no need to do that as the Swift standard library can just initialise an Int using the `init?<S: StringProtocol>(_ text: S, radix: Int)` initialiser on `FixedWidthInteger`, passing a radix of 16. Assuming you know that the colors are always in RGB format and you're wanting a SwiftUI `Color`, you can parse like this:

```
func parseRGB(fromHex hexString: String) -> Color? {
    guard let hex = Int(hexString.trimmingPrefix("#"), radix: 16) else { return nil }
    return Color(
        red: Double((hex >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
        green: Double((hex >> 8) & 0xff) / 255,
        blue: Double(hex & 0xff) / 255
    )
}
```

Comment: It seems to work with `Int32` though. Do you need 64 bits if the most you're shifting is 16?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.0:

In viewDidLoad()

```
 var viewColor:UIColor
    viewColor = UIColor()
    let colorInt:UInt
    colorInt = 0x000000
    viewColor = UIColorFromRGB(colorInt)
    self.View.backgroundColor=viewColor



func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIColor {
    public convenience init?(hex: String) {
        let r, g, b, a: CGFloat

        if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
            let start = hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
            let hexColor = String(hex[start...])

            if hexColor.count == 8 {
                let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
                var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

                if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {
                    r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                    g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
                    b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                    a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255

                    self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let white = UIColor(hex: "#ffffff")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5

```
extension UIColor{

/// Converting hex string to UIColor
///
/// - Parameter hexString: input hex string
convenience init(hexString: String) {
    let hex = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
    var int = UInt64()
    Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt64(&int)
    let a, r, g, b: UInt64
    switch hex.count {
    case 3:    
        (a, r, g, b) = (255, (int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)
    case 6: 
        (a, r, g, b) = (255, int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
    case 8: 
        (a, r, g, b) = (int >> 24, int >> 16 & 0xFF, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
    default:
        (a, r, g, b) = (255, 0, 0, 0)
    }
    self.init(red: CGFloat(r) / 255, green: CGFloat(g) / 255, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255, alpha: CGFloat(a) / 255)
}
}
```

Call using UIColor(hexString: "your hex string")

Answer (score 1):

iOS 14, SwiftUI 2.0, swift 5.1, Xcode beta12

```
extension Color {
  static func hexColour(hexValue:UInt32)->Color
    {
      let red = Double((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
      let green = Double((hexValue & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0
      let blue = Double(hexValue & 0xFF) / 255.0
      return Color(red:red, green:green, blue:blue)
    }
}
```

You call it with a hex number

```
let red = Color.hexColour(hexValue: 0xFF0000)
```

Answer (score 1):

[A neat extension by Marco Eidinger](https://blog.eidinger.info/from-hex-to-color-and-back-in-swiftui) for SwiftUI:

Hex to `Color`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    init?(hex: String) {
        var hexSanitized = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        hexSanitized = hexSanitized.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")

        var rgb: UInt64 = 0

        var r: CGFloat = 0.0
        var g: CGFloat = 0.0
        var b: CGFloat = 0.0
        var a: CGFloat = 1.0

        let length = hexSanitized.count

        guard Scanner(string: hexSanitized).scanHexInt64(&rgb) else { return nil }

        if length == 6 {
            r = CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
            g = CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0
            b = CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0

        } else if length == 8 {
            r = CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0
            g = CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
            b = CGFloat((rgb & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255.0
            a = CGFloat(rgb & 0x000000FF) / 255.0

        } else {
            return nil
        }

        self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, opacity: a)
    }
}
```

`Color` to hex:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

extension Color {
    func toHex() -> String? {
        let uic = UIColor(self)
        guard let components = uic.cgColor.components, components.count >= 3 else {
            return nil
        }
        let r = Float(components[0])
        let g = Float(components[1])
        let b = Float(components[2])
        var a = Float(1.0)

        if components.count >= 4 {
            a = Float(components[3])
        }

        if a != Float(1.0) {
            return String(format: "%02lX%02lX%02lX%02lX", lroundf(r * 255), lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(b * 255), lroundf(a * 255))
        } else {
            return String(format: "%02lX%02lX%02lX", lroundf(r * 255), lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(b * 255))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Supporting 7 Hex color types

There are 7 hex color formats: ""#FF0000","0xFF0000", "FF0000", "F00", "red", 0x00FF00 , 16711935

```
NSColorParser.nsColor("#FF0000",1)//red nsColor
NSColorParser.nsColor("FF0",1)//red nsColor
NSColorParser.nsColor("0xFF0000",1)//red nsColor
NSColorParser.nsColor("#FF0000",1)//red nsColor
NSColorParser.nsColor("FF0000",1)//red nsColor
NSColorParser.nsColor(0xFF0000,1)//red nsColor
NSColorParser.nsColor(16711935,1)//red nsColor
```

**CAUTION:** This isn't a "one-file-solution", there are some dependencies, but hunting them down may be faster than researching this from scratch.

https://github.com/eonist/swift-utils/blob/2882002682c4d2a3dc7cb3045c45f66ed59d566d/geom/color/NSColorParser.swift

**Permalink:**
https://github.com/eonist/Element/wiki/Progress#supporting-7-hex-color-types

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.0

The code below is tested on xcode 7.2

```
import UIKit
extension UIColor{

    public convenience init?(colorCodeInHex: String, alpha: Float = 1.0){

        var filterColorCode:String =  colorCodeInHex.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#", withString: "")

        if  filterColorCode.characters.count != 6 {
            self.init(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
            return
        }

        filterColorCode = filterColorCode.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).uppercaseString

        var range = Range(start: filterColorCode.startIndex.advancedBy(0), end: filterColorCode.startIndex.advancedBy(2))
        let rString = filterColorCode.substringWithRange(range)

        range = Range(start: filterColorCode.startIndex.advancedBy(2), end: filterColorCode.startIndex.advancedBy(4))
        let gString = filterColorCode.substringWithRange(range)


        range = Range(start: filterColorCode.startIndex.advancedBy(4), end: filterColorCode.startIndex.advancedBy(6))
        let bString = filterColorCode.substringWithRange(range)

        var r:CUnsignedInt = 0, g:CUnsignedInt = 0, b:CUnsignedInt = 0;
        NSScanner(string: rString).scanHexInt(&r)
        NSScanner(string: gString).scanHexInt(&g)
        NSScanner(string: bString).scanHexInt(&b)


        self.init(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.0:

Make an extension of UIColor.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hexString:String) {
        let hexString:NSString = hexString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        let scanner            = NSScanner(string: hexString as String)
        if (hexString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            scanner.scanLocation = 1
        }

        var color:UInt32 = 0
        scanner.scanHexInt(&color)

        let mask = 0x000000FF
        let r = Int(color >> 16) & mask
        let g = Int(color >> 8) & mask
        let b = Int(color) & mask

        let red   = CGFloat(r) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat(g) / 255.0
        let blue  = CGFloat(b) / 255.0
        self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:1)
    }

    func toHexString() -> String {
        var r:CGFloat = 0
        var g:CGFloat = 0
        var b:CGFloat = 0
        var a:CGFloat = 0
        getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        let rgb:Int = (Int)(r*255)<<16 | (Int)(g*255)<<8 | (Int)(b*255)<<0
        return NSString(format:"#%06x", rgb) as String
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
//Hex to Color
    let countPartColor =  UIColor(hexString: "E43038")

//Color to Hex
let colorHexString =  UIColor(red: 228, green: 48, blue: 56, alpha: 1.0).toHexString()
```

Comment: Please avoid posting [duplicate answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35428135/2227743). If a question is a duplicate, flag it as such instead of answering. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**For swift 3**

```
extension String {
    var hexColor: UIColor {        
        let hex = trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
        var int = UInt32()       
        Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt32(&int)
        let a, r, g, b: UInt32
        switch hex.characters.count {
        case 3: // RGB (12-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, (int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)
        case 6: // RGB (24-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        case 8: // ARGB (32-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (int >> 24, int >> 16 & 0xFF, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        default:
            return .clear
        }
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r) / 255, green: CGFloat(g) / 255, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255, alpha: CGFloat(a) / 255)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension on UIColor which converts Your String (Hexadecimal , RGBA) to UIColor and vice versa.

```
extension UIColor {

  //Convert RGBA String to UIColor object
  //"rgbaString" must be separated by space "0.5 0.6 0.7 1.0" 50% of Red 60% of Green 70% of Blue Alpha 100%
  public convenience init?(rgbaString : String){
      self.init(ciColor: CIColor(string: rgbaString))
  }

  //Convert UIColor to RGBA String
  func toRGBAString()-> String {
    var r: CGFloat = 0
    var g: CGFloat = 0
    var b: CGFloat = 0
    var a: CGFloat = 0
    self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
    return "\(r) \(g) \(b) \(a)"
  }

  //return UIColor from Hexadecimal Color string
  public convenience init?(hexString: String) {  
    let r, g, b, a: CGFloat

    if hexString.hasPrefix("#") {
      let start = hexString.index(hexString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
      let hexColor = hexString.substring(from: start)

      if hexColor.characters.count == 8 {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
        var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

        if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {
          r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
          g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
          b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
          a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255
          self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
          return
        }
      }
    }

    return nil
  }

  // Convert UIColor to Hexadecimal String
  func toHexString() -> String {
    var r: CGFloat = 0
    var g: CGFloat = 0
    var b: CGFloat = 0
    var a: CGFloat = 0
    self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
    return String(
        format: "%02X%02X%02X",
        Int(r * 0xff),
        Int(g * 0xff),
        Int(b * 0xff))
  }
}
```

Comment: Alpha is not supported in toHexString()

Answer (score 0):

UIColor extension, This will greatly help you! (version：**Swift 4.0**)

```
import UIKit
extension UIColor {
/// rgb颜色
convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
    self.init(red: r/255.0 ,green: g/255.0 ,blue: b/255.0 ,alpha:1.0)
}

/// 纯色（用于灰色）
convenience init(gray: CGFloat) {
    self.init(red: gray/255.0 ,green: gray/255.0 ,blue: gray/255.0 ,alpha:1.0)
}
/// 随机色
class func randomCGColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(r: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)), g: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)), b: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)))
}

/// hex颜色-Int
convenience init(hex:Int, alpha:CGFloat = 1.0) {
    self.init(
        red:   CGFloat((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((hex & 0x00FF00) >> 8)  / 255.0,
        blue:  CGFloat((hex & 0x0000FF) >> 0)  / 255.0,
        alpha: alpha
    )
}
/// hex颜色-String
convenience init(hexString: String){
    var red:   CGFloat = 0.0
    var green: CGFloat = 0.0
    var blue:  CGFloat = 0.0
    var alpha: CGFloat = 1.0
    let scanner = Scanner(string: hexString)
    var hexValue: CUnsignedLongLong = 0
    if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexValue) {
        switch (hexString.characters.count) {
        case 3:
            red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xF00) >> 8)       / 15.0
            green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0F0) >> 4)       / 15.0
            blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x00F)              / 15.0
        case 4:
            red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xF000) >> 12)     / 15.0
            green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0F00) >> 8)      / 15.0
            blue  = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00F0) >> 4)      / 15.0
            alpha = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x000F)             / 15.0
        case 6:
            red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)   / 255.0
            green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8)    / 255.0
            blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x0000FF)           / 255.0
        case 8:
            alpha = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0
            red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
            green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0000FF00) >> 8)  / 255.0
            blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x000000FF)         / 255.0
        default:
            log.info("Invalid RGB string, number of characters after '#' should be either 3, 4, 6 or 8")
        }
    } else {
        log.error("Scan hex error")
    }
    self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
}}
```

Comment: just a combination of the previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

## RGBA Version Swift 3/4

I like @Luca's answer as i think it's the most elegant.

***However*** I don't want my colours specified in **ARGB**. I'd rather **RGBA** + also i needed to hack in the case of dealing with strings that specify 1 character for each of the channels "**#FFFA**".

This version also adds error throwing + strips the '#' character if it's included in the string.
Here is my modified form for Swift.

```
public enum ColourParsingError: Error
{
    
    case invalidInput(String)
}
extension UIColor {
    public convenience init(hexString: String) throws
    {
        let hexString = hexString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")
        let hex = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in:NSCharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
        var int = UInt32()
        Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt32(&int)
        let a, r, g, b: UInt32
        switch hex.count 
        {
        case 3: // RGB (12-bit)
            (r, g, b,a) = ((int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17,255)
        //iCSS specification in the form of #F0FA
        case 4: // RGB (24-bit)
            (r, g, b,a) = ((int >> 12) * 17, (int >> 8 & 0xF) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)
        case 6: // RGB (24-bit)
            (r, g, b, a) = (int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF,255)
        case 8: // ARGB (32-bit)
            (r, g, b, a) = (int >> 24, int >> 16 & 0xFF, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        default:
            throw ColourParsingError.invalidInput("String is not a valid hex colour string: \(hexString)")
        }
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r) / 255, green: CGFloat(g) / 255, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255, alpha: CGFloat(a) / 255)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIColor(hexString: "#ffffff")
```

.

```
extension UIColor {
  convenience init?(hexString hex: String) {
    var cString: String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if cString.hasPrefix("#") {
      cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    guard cString.count == 6 else {
      return nil
    }

    var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)

    self.init(
      red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
      green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
      blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
      alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just some addiotion to the first answer

(haven't cehcked the alpha, may need to add an `if netHext > 0xffffff`):

```
extension UIColor {

struct COLORS_HEX {
    static let Primary = 0xffffff
    static let PrimaryDark = 0x000000
    static let Accent = 0xe89549
    static let AccentDark = 0xe27b2a
    static let TextWhiteSemiTransparent = 0x80ffffff
}

convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int, alphaH: Int) {
    assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
    assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
    assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")
    assert(alphaH >= 0 && alphaH <= 255, "Invalid alpha component")

    self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(alphaH) / 255.0)
}

convenience init(netHex:Int) {
    self.init(red:(netHex >> 16) & 0xff, green:(netHex >> 8) & 0xff, blue:netHex & 0xff, alphaH: (netHex >> 24) & 0xff)
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a small function,placed it from where I can use it globally & working fine with swift 2.1:

```
func getColorFromHex(rgbValue:UInt32)->UIColor{
   let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0
   let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0
   let blue = CGFloat(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0

   return UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:1.0)
}
```

usage:

```
getColorFromHex(0xffffff)
```

Comment: You should be dividing by `255` not `256`. There is no way to get white using your code. Only "almost white".

Answer (score -1):

Swift 2.3:
UIColor Extension. I Think its simpler.

```
extension UIColor {
    static func colorFromHex(hexString: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1) -> UIColor {
        //checking if hex has 7 characters or not including '#'
        if hexString.characters.count < 7 {
            return UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
        //string by removing hash
        let hexStringWithoutHash = hexString.substringFromIndex(hexString.startIndex.advancedBy(1))

        //I am extracting three parts of hex color Red (first 2 characters), Green (middle 2 characters), Blue (last two characters)
        let eachColor = [
            hexStringWithoutHash.substringWithRange(hexStringWithoutHash.startIndex...hexStringWithoutHash.startIndex.advancedBy(1)),
            hexStringWithoutHash.substringWithRange(hexStringWithoutHash.startIndex.advancedBy(2)...hexStringWithoutHash.startIndex.advancedBy(3)),
            hexStringWithoutHash.substringWithRange(hexStringWithoutHash.startIndex.advancedBy(4)...hexStringWithoutHash.startIndex.advancedBy(5))]

        let hexForEach = eachColor.map {CGFloat(Int($0, radix: 16) ?? 0)} //radix is base of numeric system you want to convert to, Hexadecimal has base 16

        //return the color by making color
        return UIColor(red: hexForEach[0] / 255, green: hexForEach[1] / 255, blue: hexForEach[2] / 255, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let color = UIColor.colorFromHex("#25ac09")
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 4.0**

use this Single line of method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   let color = UIColor(hexColor: "FF00A0")
   self.view.backgroundColor = color

}
```

You have to create new Class or use any controller where u need to use Hex color. This extension class provide you UIColor that will convert Hex to RGB color.

```
extension UIColor {
convenience init(hexColor: String) {
    let scannHex = Scanner(string: hexColor)
    var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0
    scannHex.scanLocation = 0
    scannHex.scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
    let r = (rgbValue & 0xff0000) >> 16
    let g = (rgbValue & 0xff00) >> 8
    let b = rgbValue & 0xff
    self.init(
        red: CGFloat(r) / 0xff,
        green: CGFloat(g) / 0xff,
        blue: CGFloat(b) / 0xff, alpha: 1
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Again, that unnecessary usage of strings. Also, you are just copying the other answers.

Answer (score -2):

```
extension UIColor {

      convenience init(hex: Int, alpha: Double = 1.0) {

      self.init(red: CGFloat((hex>>16)&0xFF)/255.0, green:CGFloat((hex>>8)&0xFF)/255.0, blue: CGFloat((hex)&0xFF)/255.0, alpha:  CGFloat(255 * alpha) / 255)
     }
}
```

Use this extension like:

```
let selectedColor = UIColor(hex: 0xFFFFFF)
let selectedColor = UIColor(hex: 0xFFFFFF, alpha: 0.5)
```

Comment: Utility classes are an antipattern in Swift. Swift has extensions.

Answer (score -2):

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat = 1) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: a)
    }

    convenience init(hex: Int, alpha: CGFloat = 1) {
        self.init(r: CGFloat((hex >> 16) & 0xff), g: CGFloat((hex >> 08) & 0xff), b: CGFloat((hex >> 00) & 0xff), a: alpha)
    }
}
```