# How to programmatically use hex colors to change view bg?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

`view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()`

changes the background but it's limited to few colors, is there a way to use hex color codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use extensions

```
    extension UIColor
    {
        class func myGreenColor() -> UIColor
        {
            return UIColor(red: 0.145, green: 0.608, blue: 0.141, alpha: 1.0)/*#259b24*/
        }
     }
```

this [web](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/web-color-to-uicolor-convertor/) converts hex to UIColor is objective-c , it should be easy for you to turn objective-c code into swift :P :D

Comment: How would I use NSUserDefaults to save the certain color class for the user? If the user selected `myGreenColor()` and it wasn't in viewDidLoad, how would I get it to save the color the user selected? @user3703910

Comment: sorry I didn't get your question , can you explain better :D ?

Comment: you should just use a computed var instead of a class function

Comment: okay, let's say you have a user that is using your app, and they have 5 choices to choose from the change the background color, green, blue, purple, white, and black. Let's say the user selects blue as their default background color, how would i get that to save so the blue is always the default color for the background? @user3703910

Comment: I need to sleep so I'll give a quick solution , the simplest way is to save the user's wanted color in NSUserDefaults (I suggest to make a const string , (like : let myBlackColor = "my black color"),
and when the user choses black , save myBlackColor to his NSUserDefaults , and then , in viewDidLoad , make switch (the swifts switch is very powerful ) , and get the color from NSUserDefaults , and change the back ground color . got it ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in hex converter, but the one here works well for swift. Also has RGB converter if you prefer that.

[How to use hex colour values in Swift, iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263007/how-to-use-hex-colour-values-in-swift-ios)

Code from accepted answer linked above:

```
extension UIColor {
   convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
       assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
       assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
       assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")

       self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
   }

   convenience init(netHex:Int) {
       self.init(red:(netHex >> 16) & 0xff, green:(netHex >> 8) & 0xff, blue:netHex & 0xff)
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
var color = UIColor(red: 0xFF, blue: 0xFF, green: 0xFF)
var color2 = UIColor(netHex:0xFFFFFF)
```