# Swift border color

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have color border on button:

```
buyButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 83.0, green: 186.0, blue: 183.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

doesn't work for me, but

```
 buyButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

works. What is wrong with my color?

Thank you

Comment: Are you setting borderWidth as well?

Comment: set border width also

Comment: Read the doc of `UIColor(red:green:blue:alpha:)`. The wanted values needs to be between 0 and 1. so `83.0` => `83.0/255.0`

Comment: Use an extension that takes `Int` instead of `CGFloat`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24263296/669586

Comment: Yes I'm setting borderWidth as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input values needs to be between 0 and 1, so divide them by 255.

```
buyButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 83.0/255.0, green: 186.0/255.0, blue: 183.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'raw' RGB values, divide them by 255.0.

```
buyButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 83.0/255.0, green: 186.0/255.0, blue: 183.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

So in UIColor terms, 1.0 is 255 red. 0.5 is 127.5 red etc.