# Convert RGBA HEX to UIColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, hex, uicolor, rgba

In Objective-C, does anyone know how to convert a RGBA HEX color, such as, #6FFFFFFF, to a UIColor?

The first two characters, 6F, are the alpha channel and the remaining 6 characters are the red, green, and blue channels. In this case 6F is about 0.5 and FFFFFF is white.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/24263007/189804 (trivial to add the alpha component to any of the code given)

Comment: @AdamEberbach Still not seeing how to convert a hex to alpha from either of those duplicate questions. How do I convert 6F to a alpha?