# Showing JSON multicolors in SwiftyCharts

Tags: ios, json, swift, charts

In my application i was implemented a `SwiftyCharts` inside that i need to show the multi color based on the gender selection in `JSON` value.In my case am getting an value from json, that returns multi colors only. But i cannot show can any one please help me to fix this.

Below code only used for color conversion:

```
func hexToRGBConversion(hex:String) -> UIColor {

    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

Note:

```
employeeColorCode.append(self.hexToRGBConversion(hex: json[i]["ColorCode"].description))
```

Comment: explain more what you want?

Comment: if suppose you are choosing an gender chart means in X axis i have to show gender based on that gender selection colors will be changed.In Y axis count will be displayed.

Comment: you want hex to UIColor?

Comment: Am converted by the above mentioned code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use hex colour values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263007/how-to-use-hex-colour-values)

Comment: @preethacmu try below two function it's working for me perfect.

Comment: @preethacmu what is this value json[i]["ColorCode"].description?

Answer (score 1):

Try this UIColor extension method,

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hex: String) {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hex)
        scanner.scanLocation = 0

        if (hex.hasPrefix("#")) {
           scanner.scanLocation = 1
        }

        var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0

        scanner.scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)

        let r = (rgbValue & 0xff0000) >> 16
        let g = (rgbValue & 0xff00) >> 8
        let b = rgbValue & 0xff

        self.init(
            red: CGFloat(r) / 0xff,
            green: CGFloat(g) / 0xff,
            blue: CGFloat(b) / 0xff, alpha: 1
        )
    }
}
```

You can use it like this way,

```
let color = UIColor(hex: "FF0000")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

create UIColor **Extension**.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hexString: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        let hexString: String = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hexString)
        if (hexString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            scanner.scanLocation = 1
        }
        var color: UInt32 = 0
        scanner.scanHexInt32(&color)
        let mask = 0x000000FF
        let r = Int(color >> 16) & mask
        let g = Int(color >> 8) & mask
        let b = Int(color) & mask
        let red   = CGFloat(r) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat(g) / 255.0
        let blue  = CGFloat(b) / 255.0
        self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
    }
    func toHexString() -> String {
        var r:CGFloat = 0
        var g:CGFloat = 0
        var b:CGFloat = 0
        var a:CGFloat = 0
        getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        let rgb:Int = (Int)(r*255)<<16 | (Int)(g*255)<<8 | (Int)(b*255)<<0
        return String(format:"#%06x", rgb)
    }
}
```

Use like this.

```
let color = UIColor(hexString: "#3f3f3f")
```

2 also you have only color code then create Extension like this.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(rgb: UInt) {
      self.init(
          red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
          green: CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
          blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
          alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
      )
  }
}
```

use like this.

```
let color = UIColor(rgb: 0x1BCAAB)
```

Comment: Passing the single color is working fine while using array of color it takes  a last index.

Comment: var employeeColorCode :  [UIColor] = [] . 
   employeeColorCode.append(UIColor.init(hexString: orgjson[i]["ColorCode"].description))

Comment: @preethacmu please show value of this "orgjson[i]["ColorCode"].description"

Comment: [
  {
    "ColorCode" : "#a4cbd8",
    "gender" : "Male",
    "genderCount" : 24
  },
  {
    "ColorCode" : "#CC0000",
    "gender" : "Female",
    "genderCount" : 20
  }
]

Comment: @preethacmu remove .description and try.

Comment: while removing the description means getting "Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type 'Subscript'" error.

Comment: @preethacmu one more try this : ((orgjson as! NSArray).object(at: i) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "ColorCode") as! String

Comment: tried facing an issue 'JSON' is not convertible to 'NSArray'

Comment: @preethacmu try to use .string instead of .description.

Comment: Based on your last comment,i changed but no color is appear on my chart.