# How do I set UIColor from Int?

Tags: swift, background-color, uicolor

So There are answers to this on SO but they are old and as far as I can tell in `objectiveC`, so...

I want to set the `backgroundcolor` using `Int` variables passed from a different `view`, like this:

```
backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 0.5)
```

The variables `red` `green` `blue` used are like this:

```
var red: Int!
var green: Int!
var blue: Int!
```

With numbers from the previous `view` of course.

Xcode wants me to convert it to `CGFloat` like this:

```
backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 0.5)
```

But then the right color isn't carried over and only grey is shown.

I tried changing the `Int` variables to `UIColor`

```
var red: UIColor!
```

But that gave me an error...

So, how do I fix this?

Comment: What values are you storing in `red`, `green` and `blue`?

Comment: For view1: red = 144, green = 183, blue = 56, view2: red = 225, green = 163, blue = 38, view3: red = 186, green = 0, blue = 19, view4: red = 122, green = 28, blue = 125. Same result on all views...

Comment: Type `let red = 144; print(red / 255)` into a Playground and you'll see the problem! (This is called “debugging” :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263007/how-to-use-hex-colour-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the value to float before dividing it by 255, otherwise it will make the division by two integers resulting always in 0:

```
CGFloat(red) / 255 = 0.5647058823529412
CGFloat(red / 255) = 0

backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red) / 255, green: CGFloat(green) / 255, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255, alpha: 0.5)
```

Comment: Yepp! There it is! Xcode autocorrected it to the one that didn't work. Now it works like a charm, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red)/255.0, green: CGFloat(green)/255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue)/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
```