# SwiftUI: How to set background color by color name string

Tags: swift, string, colors, swiftui

I have `var color: String = "blue"`. With that variable I want to set the background color of a Button. I tried `.background(Color(color))`, but that doesn't work. `.background(Color.blue)` or `.background(Color(.blue))` work, but I want to use the String variable for it. How to do this?

Comment: To create a color from a string you need to have added that color to your assets catalog

Comment: If you want to store colors as strings, a [hex code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24263296/14351818) works pretty well

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this. Are you porting code from another language?

Comment: @PietroRea I have a .json file with colors stored by their name

Answer (score 2):

You could compare the string which comes in and get the correct color from that. See the following example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Color(wordName: "red")
    }
}


extension Color {
    
    init?(wordName: String) {
        switch wordName {
        case "clear":       self = .clear
        case "black":       self = .black
        case "white":       self = .white
        case "gray":        self = .gray
        case "red":         self = .red
        case "green":       self = .green
        case "blue":        self = .blue
        case "orange":      self = .orange
        case "yellow":      self = .yellow
        case "pink":        self = .pink
        case "purple":      self = .purple
        case "primary":     self = .primary
        case "secondary":   self = .secondary
        default:            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had hoped that this would not be necessary, but thank you

Comment: @nils I hoped it would be easier to do. I just took this code from one of my current projects and changed it to work best for you