# Equivalent of Swift &+ in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, swift, hash

I'm not able to get the same `djbhash` in JavaScript that I was getting in Swift.

```
extension String {
    public func djbHash() -> Int {
        return self.utf8
            .map {return $0}
            .reduce(5381) {
                let h = ($0 << 5) &+ $0 &+ Int($1)
                print("h", h)
                return h
            }
    }
}
```

```
var djbHash = function (string) {
    var h = 5381; // our hash
    var i = 0; // our iterator

    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var ascii = string.charCodeAt(i); // grab ASCII integer
        h = (h << 5) + h + ascii; // bitwise operations
    }
    return h;
}
```

I tried using `BigInt`, but the value for the string "QHChLUHDMNh5UTBUcgtLmlPziN42" I'm getting is 17760568308754997342052348842020823769412069976n, compared to 357350748206983768 in Swift.

Comment: it would be helpful to post some reference results string->hash from your swift code, so that posters can test their js solutions.

Comment: test string "QHChLUHDMNh5UTBUcgtLmlPziN42"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift `&+` operator is an [“overflow operator”](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID37): It truncates the result of the addition to the available number of bits for the used integer type.

A Swift `Int` is a 64-bit (signed) integer on all 64-bit platforms, and adding two integers would crash with a runtime exception if the result does not fit into an `Int`:

```
let a: Int = 0x7ffffffffffffff0
let b: Int = 0x7ffffffffffffff0
print(a + b) //  Swift runtime failure: arithmetic overflow
```

With `&+` the result is truncated to 64-bit:

```
let a: Int = 0x7ffffffffffffff0
let b: Int = 0x7ffffffffffffff0
print(a &+ b) // -32
```

In order to get the same result with JavaScript and BigInt one can use the `BigInt.asIntN()` function:

```
var a = 0x7ffffffffffffff0n
var b = 0x7ffffffffffffff0n
console.log(a + b) // 18446744073709551584n
console.log(BigInt.asIntN(64, a+b)) // -32n
```

With that change, the JavaScript function gives the same result as your Swift code:

```
var djbHash = function (string) {
    var h = 5381n; // our hash
    var i = 0; // our iterator

    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var code = string.charCodeAt(i); // grab UTF-16 code point
        h = BigInt.asIntN(64, (h << 5n) + h + BigInt(code)); // bitwise operations
    }
    return h;
}

console.log(djbHash("QHChLUHDMNh5UTBUcgtLmlPziN42")) // 357350748206983768n
```

As mentioned in the comments to the other answer, `charCodeAt()` returns UTF-16 code points, whereas your Swift function works with the UTF-8 representation of a string. So this will still give different results for strings containing any non-ASCII characters.

For identical results for arbitrary strings (umlauts, Emojis, flags, ...) its best to work with the Unicode code points. In Swift that would be

```
extension String {
    public func djbHash() -> Int {
        return self.unicodeScalars
            .reduce(5381) { ($0 << 5) &+ $0 &+ Int($1.value) }
    }
}

print("äöü€".djbHash()) // 6958626281456
```

(You may also consider to use `Int64` instead of `Int` for platform-independent code, or `Int32` if a 32-bit hash is sufficient.)

The corresponding JavaScript code is

```
var djbHash = function (string) {
    var h = 5381n; // our hash
    
    for (const codePoint of string) {
        h = BigInt.asIntN(64, (h << 5n) + h + BigInt(codePoint.codePointAt(0))); // bitwise operations
    }
    return h;
}

console.log(djbHash("äöü€")) // 6958626281456n
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue in which I've used the `&` in combination with the used operator. I think the code below should work. It's still under review but you can checkout my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74178538/bitshifting-in-swiftui-how-to-convert-string-using-a-hash-to-a-specific-array-i)

```
var djbHash = function (string) {
    var h = 5381; // our hash
    var i = 0; // our iterator

    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var ascii = string.charCodeAt(i); // grab ASCII integer
        h = (h << 5) + h &+ ascii; // bitwise operations
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: I am getting 0 for this

Comment: its returning 0, do u have any idea why's that ? @Wouter

Comment: Well, not entirely sure. But I believe it has to do with the types of encoding you're using. In Javascript CharcodeAt uses utf16 by default. I've tried your code in playgrounds and I returns the same result. CharcodeAt doesnt return ASCII. Problem is I don't really understand why you would need such a value so having trouble reproducing and understanding your issue completely :(

Comment: well my project uses firebase realtime db and node.js server, I need to create that hash to query realtime from both swift and node. the hash has to be the same on both sides. does this make sense ? im basically looking for table entries with that hash ?

Comment: does it return the same hash for "QHChLUHDMNh5UTBUcgtLmlPziN42" on both swift and node for you

Comment: there's no such thing as `&+` in javascript. When you write `a &+ b` it actually means `a & (+b)` that is, just `a & b`.

Comment: ```swift

print(gethash(string: "QHChLUHDMNh5UTBUcgtLmlPziN42")) //returns "357350748206983768"
func gethash(string: String) -> Int {
    var hash = 5381; // our hash

    let count = string.count;
    let nameAsUnicode = string.utf16

    for unicode in nameAsUnicode {
        var bitShift = ((hash << 5) &+ hash )
        hash = Int(unicode) + bitShift;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Maybe I've read your article wrong but keep getting this as a result.

Comment: Any idea @gog how I would get the same hash for JS