# Trying to use RGB colors without a storyboard or color wheel in swift4 xcode9

Tags: colors, swift4, xcode9

How can I edit this code to let me use rgb colors? **btn.backgroundColor=UIColor.orange** I do not have a storyboard and need to use very specific colors. I am using swift 4 xcode 9 and everything I find is for older versions and wont work. I need this for labels text and buttons. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use UIColorFromRGB value in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074257/how-to-use-uicolorfromrgb-value-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
 btn.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 255, green: 251, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
```